# POST api authentication in vba

Tags: excel, vba, post

I am trying to connect excel (through vba) to the "teamleader" api v1, via post calls.
[api docs here](https://apidocs.teamleader.be/index.php)

I tried some solutions which I have found, regarding post calls in vba, but seem to be getting nowhere.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim url As String
    Dim objhttp As Object
    Set objhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    url = "https://app.teamleader.eu/api/helloWorld.php"

    With objhttp
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "api_group", "xxx"
        .setRequestHeader "api_secret", "xxx"
        .send
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

This however gives me this response:

```
{"status":"failed","reason":"Please set api_group."}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: That documentation is supposedly deprecated. Did you try the documentation at [](https://developer.teamleader.eu/#/introduction/ap-what?)

Comment: I did, but the older post api is supposedly still live.
The newer api uses RPC, which is a whole lot more complicated, so I would rather avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed the put all the authentication in the url itself, this question can be closed.